# how to prevent row selection by user's click while keeping programmatic row selection?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

In my app I have a QTableView with rows that get selected programmatically, e.g. after a query on the data is performed.

How can I prevent the user to change the selected rows on click, while keeping the ability to select rows programmatically?

This is my code:

```
self.table = QTableView()
pandas_model: QAbstractTableModel = PandasTableModel(self.data_frame, self)
self.table.setModel(pandas_model)
self.table.setSortingEnabled(False)
self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)  # full width table
self.table.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
self.table.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
```

Should I override its ItemSelectionModel in order to prevent the default behaviour on user click while keeping the programmatic selection mode? How could I achieve this?

Comment: Could you explain me better, do you want to disable the selection at what time? In what part of your code is selected programmatically? How long does the selection delay for programming? Generally the selection by programming is almost to the present. Maybe with a [mcve] it would help us understand you

Comment: @eyllanesc, I'll try to explain me better. This table is used to display some data loaded from a .csv, then the user can perform a query on such data. After the query is performed I select the rows of the result set on the QTableView.
Now, the user is able to also select/deselect some rows, invalidating the "view" of the performed query. For this reason I'm looking for a way to prevent the user to select/deselect rows by click.
Here https://github.com/izio7/AttributedGraphProfiler/blob/maurizio/query_rewriter/ui/tabs/DataTab.py the full source code.

Comment: 1) From what I understand you want the user can not modify the selection, and only the programmatic selection must remain, ie for example if according to the query is selected row 1.3 and 5, then the user should not be able select other rows or deselect any of rows 1,3 and 5 Am I right? 2) I have not asked for the source code of your project, I have asked for an MCVE. 3) If 1) is correct then I will propose my solution without basing myself on any MCVE.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Thanks

Comment: One more question: Can the QTableView be edited by the user or is it read-only?

Comment: It is read-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid that the user can select an item(s), row(s) or column(s) you should do the following:

- Overwrite delegate editorEvent method so that it does not notify the view click.
- Deactivate the ability to click on the sections of the headers

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        res = super(Delegate, self).editorEvent(event, model, option, index)
        if event.type() in (
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress,
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease,
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick,
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove,
            QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress
        ):
            return True
        return res


class TableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TableView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch
        )
        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        delegate = Delegate(self)
        self.setItemDelegate(delegate)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionsClickable(False)
        self.verticalHeader().setSectionsClickable(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    for i in range(15):
        for j in range(6):
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem("{}-{}".format(i, j))
            model.setItem(i, j, it)

    table = TableView()
    table.setModel(model)

    # emulate select by query
    import random

    for row in random.sample(range(model.rowCount()), 5):
        table.selectRow(row)

    table.resize(640, 480)
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I also noticed that the spacebar press could affect the selection/deselection of a row, so I added `QEvent.KeyPress` to the events to ignore.